# converting factor timestamps to time formats in R

Tags: r, time, format, timestamp

I have the following time format for a variable that is a factor

2004-03-01-22.58.00.912933

I am using R and would like to make this something that is an actual time format.  Others have posted similar questions but no one has dealt with this time format specifically.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your factor is `f1`:

```
as.POSIXct(levels(f1), format = "%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%OS")[f1]
```

If the fractions don't display, set the option:

```
op <- options(digits.secs = 3)
```

Comment: When I do this I get a bunch of NAs. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: Can you reproduce a minimal example? dput?